# filebeat :7.3.2 POD OOMKilled with 1Gi memory

Tags: kubernetes, filebeat

I am running filebeat as deamon set with 1Gi memory setting. my pods getting crashed with `OOMKilled` status.

Here is my limit setting

```
 resources:
          limits:
            memory: 1Gi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 1Gi
```

What is the recommended memory setting to run the filebeat.

Thanks

Comment: what's the kubelet setting in your environment? Go through this url: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/out-of-resource/#best-practices

Comment: This out of memory pod resource limit setting. kubelet set to this value `memory.available: 100Mi`

Answer (score 1):

The RAM usage of Filebeat is relative to how much it is doing, in general. You can limit the number of harvesters to try and reduce things, but overall you just need to run it uncapped and measure what the normal usage is for your use case and scenario.